# Update non-empty values only in mysql table

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update

My issue is that I have a PHP FORM that is submitting values through more than 55 input-text-fields, into a MySQL table.

Now, when I use UPDATE feature, suppose for e.g for 3 fields:

```
$sql="UPDATE pathology_test_rates SET bsugar_random='$bsugar_random', bsugar_fasting='$bsugar_fasting', bsugar_pp='$bsugar_pp'";
```

And then , if I want to update only 1 value, out of above 3, using PHP FORM, its making other 2 values empty.
Whereas, I want other 2 values to remain un-disturbed.

How to do this ?
Please help.
M not using id in table.

Comment: use WHERE ? = ? or $sql="UPDATE pathology_test_rates SET bsugar_random='$bsugar_random'"; for one column it will update whole column data use where for one row

Comment: You skipped the `WHERE` statement on your query.

Answer (score 0):

You can use where condition to update for example

```
$sql = "update datatwo set age = 30 where employeeid = 40;"
```